# Button and Text is merging at the time of page loading

Tags: html, css

We have "ADD TO CART" button in the [page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html), that is merging with the above text at the time of page loading.

[image]

**once loading is completed, it will display in proper position**.

[image]

```
.product-options-bottom {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 45px !important;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
```

Comment: Please add html code here..

Comment: it simply means the css is getting loaded after the HTML elements have been loaded. To resolve this put css for that element before rendering the elements.

Comment: load style first before HTML elements.

Comment: @viveksinghggits we used internal css  & placed css code under `<style>` tag , still not working for us.

Comment: @Khurram we used internal css & placed css code under <style> tag , still not working for us

Comment: @css beginner Your .product-options-bottom style is OK. problem is with your required element above it. assign inline stye display: block; to required field element with class name of last.

Comment: @cssbeginner make sure the style tag you are talking about is before the element .product-shop, or just make an external css and import it at the starting of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see your HTML but I guess your css style is not inside the head tag, move your css to head

Comment: Thanks as this is magento site, we dont have <head> , <body> & these kind of styles, can you please look at [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) & please check is any other problem causing this.....

Comment: did you add the css file in this way ? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-themes.html

Comment: yes, We are following standard magento rules, but i guess i did some bad coding related to css.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a plugin for uploading Image or Text, which take much time to load than add to cart button that's why add to cart button taking the place of uploader.

However you can get rid of this by changing CSS

```
.product-options-bottom {
        bottom: 25px !important;
}
#aitcg-control-panel .apply-but {
        bottom: 51px;
}
```

Comment: sorry i added above code,  but it did't worked for me